# asp net mvc adding a new property to model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I'm new in asp.net mvc. I'm trying to learn entity framework after the database has been created by the `first code` starting, i m adding a new porperty to model, but controller and view are not updating themselves automatically.

```
  public class test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
}
```

in this simple I add `Surname` property after database created. I update database, but view and controller side do not update themselves automatically.
So should I make all changes manually like changing controller "`create edit delete`" post action.

thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

You most likely used scaffolding to create them first. If you want to have the properties listed in the view you need to recreate the scaffolding so it knows that property exists. To do that right click on the controller folder add new scaffolded item, like you did before.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? if so please accept the answer.

Comment: yeah this is answer but not really i m looking for. why? because in this solution, i must do all code spesification again. is it true?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question i am not quite sure what you are asking.

Comment: sure. 1- i m using asp.net mvc entity framework. 2- i create a model with 2 prop. 3- i used scaffolding for controller. 4- i specified the controller with some code. 5- i need a new property in model. then i add it in model. 6- i update the database. 7- i faced a problem that in controller's post method, there is no new property which is i add last.  8- now, shall i change this controller manually. or is there any easy way.

Comment: Deleting then recreating the scaffolding is one way to do it but i think as you go on you will like to add the properties yourself in the view and controller. You will have more control of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the binding white list so your new property will be included, For this use Ctrl+Shift+B [For Visual Stdio]
after that do the Migration and update the database.